# How to copy an item from one LongListSelector to another?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

On a Panorama page I have an LongListSelector with some products. When the user clicks on an item I want to add it to another LongListSelector on the next Panorama Item. If the user clicks on the same item I will display the quantity on a TextBlock and not add it again to the next list. I don't know how to start it. I've already added the items on the first list.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user tap on an item in the list, in the `SelectionChanged` event, you'll get the selected item's object. Then, add this item to the list2 with a check that whether it is present in the list2 already or not.

```
LongListSelectorSelectionChanged()

  - if(SelectedItem in LIST2)

    Display quantity in the textbox
    return

  - else 

    Add the SelectedItem in the LIST2
    return
```

I hope your List2 is a ViewModel binded to the paranoma viewl so that the view will be changed as soon as an item is added to the List2.

Comment: SelectionChanged won't be fired the second time when user taps the same item twice.

Comment: Why it wont be? It will be fired every time a user taps.

Comment: It is not fired if you tap the currently selected item

Comment: At the end of the `SelectionChanged` function, you can deselect the current selection with `-1`

Comment: Thanks. This is my first WinPhone app, so I'm not following any specific pattern yet. I'm also using WCF to get data from SQL and I didn't found much information on how to construct an app using the recomended patterns. Got some tips or links? Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

I would handle that too in a selectionchanged event.

the easiest way for giving data to the next page is the parametervalue:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondPage.xaml?msg=JSONSTRING", UriKind.Relative));
```

Maybe serialize the Object to a JSON-String pass it over like ahead and desirialize it on the new page again to your object:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        String productsJSON = NavigationContext.QueryString["msg"];
        YourProducts product = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourProducts>(productsJSON);
```

or do you mean a panoramaItem within the same panoramapage?

Comment: My question wasn't well formulated. The second LongListSelector is on the next panoramaItem. But thanks. Now I know how to pass parameters between pages :)